# Saving object in React.useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form in my react project, and I want the value of each field to be stored in the state.
instead of having multiple states for each field, how can I store the form value as an object in the state? and more importantly how can I access it? (with react hooks)

```
import React from 'react';

export const UserData = () => {
  return(
     <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <button>Confirm</button>
     </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useState` hook. Check [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ name, email });
```

To set the state similar to `setState` in class based component:

```
setState({name: 'react', email: 'react'})
```

To access the state value:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const UserData = () => {
const [state, setState] = useState({ name, email });
  return(
     <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" value={state.name} />
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" value={state.email}  />
        <button>Confirm</button>
     </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

React Hooks allows you to define a JavaScript Object using useState. See 
https://daveceddia.com/usestate-hook-examples/

```
function LoginForm() {
   const [form, setState] = useState({
   username: '',
   password: ''
});
```

Update the form using the function :

```
const updateField = e => {
    setState({
        ...form,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }); 
};
```

Call the function onSubmit of the button

```
<form onSubmit={updateField}>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <Button >Confirm</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create an initial state value if you want to store the form values as an object using `useState`, so you can rollback to the initial state after an error. Example,

```js
const initialState = {
  name: "",
  email: ""
};

export const UserData = () => {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState(initialState);

  const submitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(formState);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Name"
        value={formState.name}
        onChange={e => {
          setFormState({ ...formState, name: e.target.value });
        }}
      />
      <input
        type="email"
        placeholder="Email"
        value={formState.email}
        onChange={e => {
          setFormState({ ...formState, email: e.target.value });
        }}
      />
      <button>Confirm</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Working demo in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-8ro6h?file=/App.js:42-775).