# React initialise state based on object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If my data is in this structure from an api:

```
{
  title: "Title", 
  id: 1,
  description: "example desc"
}
```

What would I pass in as the initial value to the state object? i.e

```
interface ObjectData {
    title: string,
    id: number,
    description: string
}

const [fetchData, setFetchData] = React.useState<ObjectData>(?// here);
```

Comment: why not update the type to `<ObjectData | undefined>`? initial state can be `undefined`

Comment: So would that mean I'don't need to pass anything through?

Comment: What initial state do you *want* `fetchData` to have?  `undefined`?  An object with `undefined` properties?  An object with properties set to default values?  Something else?  When you try, what doesn't work as expected?

Comment: @Sole You don't need to pass anything if it's okay for the initial state to be undefined

Comment: So I know for example if it was an array of objects i would initialise as `([])` but if it's just a single object like the data above, what would need to be initialised?

Comment: @Sole Isn't that something you should decide? It depends on how you plan to use the state in the component etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either if you have a default value to set (perhaps a mock) then you can set that object of type `ObjectData`.

for example

```
const defaultData: ObjectData = {
 title: 'x',
 id: -1,
 description: 'xyz',
};

...
const [fetchData, setFetchData] = React.useState<ObjectData>(defaultData);
```

Otherwise if you don't have default Data and you will get the data in the later time for example via an async API, then leave it empty. The type of `fetchData` will automatically be `fetchData: ObjectData|undefined`

```
const [fetchData, setFetchData] = React.useState<ObjectData>();
```

---

Alternatively you can explicitly typecast the empty object as ObjectData

```
const [fetchData, setFetchData] = React.useState<ObjectData>({} as ObjectData);
```

I would leave the default value empty if I will get the data in the later time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this:

```
{
  title: "Title", 
  id: 1,
  description: "example desc"
}

const [fetchData, setFetchData] = React.useState({title, id, description});
```

Grabbed from here:
[Saving object in React.useState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62116449/saving-object-in-react-usestate)